# joomla article list with descriptions

Tags: menu, joomla

On the Joomla frontpage i want to have this kind of menu

[image]

Every item has a title and description and **links to some article**.
This list must be available for modification by administrator.
Is it possible to do it? I know how to modify menu to look like this, but standart menu doesn't support descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to make it like so:

1. Make ordenery menus using Joomla! menu manager
2. Then make modules for every menu item and add menu link title and description
3. Make all menu link title on the module linked to the orginal menus you made on the first step
4. Unpublish menu module and publish these modules you just made into to the same place where was menu module

Comment: Can you please explain step 2? I don't know how to do it.